# Firebase Collaboration: Share a Single Project in Google IAM?

Tags: firebase, google-developers-console

So I shared a firebase project in Google IAM.  Turns out, the guy emails me with a screenshot and he has write access to all my projects (see below)?  Anyone else notice this, or did I add a member incorrectly?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For understanding the steps to add, please go through the below step:

1. Log in to https://console.firebase.google.com using your Google account. A screen will be displayed with option Add Project.
2. Click on the **Add Project** option. You will be asked to enter App name and country. Then proceed by clicking on **Create Project** button.
3. Click on **Users and Permission** option from **Settings/cog wheel** icon which is adjacent to **Project Overview**, present on the left menu list.
4. You will be redirected to new a webpage(https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) and proceed with accepting the terms.
5. Click on **IAM** option from the left menu list. Add member by selecting **Add** on IAM screen.
6. Provide email id and role, then click on **Add** for adding the member.